# Outlook add-in : RibbonToggleButton Image changes only refreshes when outlook window becomes active

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, synchronizationcontext

Is there any way to force a UI refresh or redraw of a control in an outlook add-in? I am basically updating the image of a button in my ribbon. The image is generated in the server via a WebApi call which contains a count of new records a new Image. This seems to be working fine unless the outlook window is not the active/focused window.

Below snippet is executed when my add-in receives a SignalR notification from the server. The snippet calls a webapi to get the new info containing the new image for the button.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when there are multiple screens/monitors connected and outlook is in the extended screen (not focused), it doesn't update the button with the new image although the code was already executed. The changes only reflects when I click/focus on outlook.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();    
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    var info = MyServerCallToGetNewCountAndImage();
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        {
        var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        uiContext.Post(b =>
            {
            MyInfo i = (MyInfo)b;
            // Update ribbon button image.
            myButton.Image = i.Image;
            }, info);
        }
});

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351196/refresh-the-office-ribbon-ui-while-the-window-is-inactive

Comment: @Stephu Yes I've seen and booked mark that one. But haven't tried it yet. I was hoping someone has got it working or worked around it with the ribbon.

Comment: I suggest normally to add a comment where you see that another person has the same problem. Maybe he has now another solution but did not write this into there...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `IRibbonUI.Invalidate`. `IRibbonUI` interface is passed to your addin when you handle the `onLoad` callback of your addin ribbon.

Comment: Yep tried that and still the same issue. You still have to click on outlook to focus before the changes take effect. One of the microsoft forums says that "As far as getting a sync context for the main thread that won't be available until the UI is active and the Window message pump has been primed in the thread."  

But I was hoping there's a workaround that people has done.

Comment: Does it get updated if the Outlook window with the ribbon is and stays active?

Comment: Yes it does. It's only an issue when outlook is not the focused window.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've had any success with this is to use a combination of invalidating the ribbon using `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` and switching to the outlook window and back to whatever was focused before.

This should be fine for a one time update, but would obviously interfere with the application if done often.